# show when onFocus and hide and onBlur combined in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, cursor

I am having a **input box** which has a list of **suggestions** for it. I want that suggestions to be only showed *when the input box is focused by cursor & hide the suggesions when the cursor removed from input box.*

currently i am doing it in a difficult way like below.

**HTML**

```
   <input ngFocus="showSuggesions('div_id') ng-blur="hideSuggesions('div_id')" >
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $scope.showSuggessions = function(div_id){
       document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "block";
    }
    $scope.hideSuggessions = function(div_id){
       document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "none";
    }
```

What i want is that

```
<input ngFocus=( iftrue ? ngShow.div_id : ngHide.div_id )>
```

I am new to angularJS, I thought doing it in a simple way would making this code more readable. I don't know angulaJS's many of the features. If this question is totally senseless I am sorry.

Comment: you can use css `:focus` https://jsfiddle.net/6auzow11/

Comment: thank you for making it easier than expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
 <input ng-focus="showSuggestions = true" ng-blur="showSuggestions = false" > 
 <div id="div_id" ng-show="showSuggestions"></div>
```

The div is the element that contains the suggestions. On focus of your input you will show the div and on blur you will hide it. Be aware, on blur it's not the same that "move the cursor away".

Careful with the spelling too of "showSuggestions".

Comment: Glad to help, ng-show and ng-hide are so useful in Angular, I use them all the time to show what I want according to variables in the scope.